# How to convert to date axis in excel?

Tags: civil-engineering

Pic(1): I tried to make a chart with date axis.

Pic(2): The right chart that I want to draw.

I tried to change the axis properties,  maximum  & minimum values to 1/24 system, but it does not  work.

Please help me to find a way to make it..

[image: Pictures of the question]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to embed the images so that we aren't forced to follow the link.

Comment: I tried but the image can't be downloaded successfully.

Comment: I think this ought to be in computing section, not engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Have a column (or row) with dates with matching the data values in the next column, then select both sets of data and plot using x-y scatter - can't test as on a smartphone...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're showing only the time, but the first column also contains the date.  Try formatting the first column as a number instead of a date/time.  The integer portion that shows is the date and the decimal portion is the time.  In order to display as you've shown, the AM times shown have to be the next day.  So if the PM times begin with a zero followed by the decimal portion, then the AM times will have to begin with a 1 followed by the decimal portion.